# Difference in files and folders at two different times (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, ntfs

I would like to see how many files and folders have been changed (including created, deleted and modified), list of changed files and folders with their **size** before and after.

So is there a utility tool (or script ?) which I could run at two different times and then get the difference ?

Comment: This is a very specific request, so, nope to a pre-canned tool. You are going to have to write this yourself. So, do some searches using your favorite search engine for each segment of your use case, to build out a script then test it, and if you then have issues, come back a see us with the code and the errors. Just search for PowerShell file and folder management as well as file and folder monitoring as well. A lot of this is in the help files on your system as well. Just look up Get-ChildItem, to get going.

Comment: @postanote thanks for comment. Btw, I'm open also to tools which do not cover all the aspects I mentioned...

Comment: You can use Treesize. It allows saving a snapshot of the files in the system at a given time and compare that to a snapshot from another time.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell it's not too difficult to just combine some cmdlets.

- `Get-ChildItem` to get the folder/file tree into an object,
- using `Export-Clixml/Import-Clixml` to store an object in a file
  (the xml files will take up some space),
- and `Compare-Object` to compare the most recent with the current tree.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\17\SU_1385185.ps1
$Base = 'C:\Test\'
$ArchiveFolder = $Env:tmp

function Archive-Tree {
    $File = "{0}\Tree_{1:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.CliXML" -f $ArchiveFolder,[datetime]::Now
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Base -Recurse | Export-Clixml $File
    $File
}

## ----- get most recent file Tree_*.clixml
$File = Get-ChildItem "$($Env:tmp)\Tree_*.Clixml" | Select-Object -Last 1
if ($File){
    $Old = Import-Clixml $File
    $New = Import-Clixml (Archive-Tree)
    Compare-Object -Ref $Old -Dif $New -Property FullName,
            Length,LastWriteTime,CreationTime,LastAccessTime |
        Sort-Object FullName,SideIndicator | Format-Table -AutoSize
} else {
    $File = (Archive-Tree)
    "No saved tree, now created as {0}" -f $File
}
```

Sample output

```
FullName              Length LastWriteTime       CreationTime        LastAccessTime      SideIndicator
--------              ------ -------------       ------------        --------------      -------------
C:\test\c_test.clixml 982258 2018-12-17 12:59:27 2018-12-17 12:59:24 2018-12-17 12:59:24 =>
C:\test\c_test.clixml      0 2018-12-17 12:59:24 2018-12-17 12:59:24 2018-12-17 12:59:24 <=
C:\Test\foo.baz         1164 2018-12-17 13:55:05 2018-12-17 13:55:21 2018-12-17 13:55:21 =>
```

The `SideIndicator <=` references the LHS or -ReferenceObject (`$OLD`),
the `SideIndicator =>` the RHS or -DifferenceObject (`$New`).